# Saving the plot using the dataframe plot function

Tags: python, pandas, plot

I'm using the data frame plot function to create the following plot:
Using the following code:

```
data.groupby(['age']).agg(np.size)['listener_id'].plot(kind='bar')
```

[image]

How can I save this plot?

Answer (score 0):

The pandas plotting function wraps matplotlib. You can save these using something like

`plt.savefig('<filename>.png')`

Comment: I tried this actually `plt.savefig("~/Documents/folder/age.pdf")` but it says file does not exist

Comment: Try creating a figure and axis using `fig, ax = plt.subplots()` and then pass `ax = ax` into the pandas plotting command.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
bplot = data.groupby(['age']).agg(np.size)['listener_id'].plot(kind='bar')
fig = bplot.get_figure()
fig.savefig("test.png")
```